# Trying to overcome something with my dictionary and loop

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code and I was wondering if any of you could take a look at it and see what is wrong. The error I keep getting in dictionary length change while iterating. How do I fix this????? Basically what is happening is that I can add things just fine and they work well, but when I go to actually take flies out (because they die) it says that it wont work becuase dictionary size keeps changing. Please help

```
import random
from random import randint

deathage = 30
startingpop = 3
rateofreproduction = 0
howmanynewflies = 2


def gennew ():
    i = 0
    list = []
    while i < 11:
        i = i + 1
        x = randint (1,4)
        if x == 1:
            list.append( "A")
        elif x == 2:
            list.append( "T")
        elif x == 3:
            list.append("C")
        else:
            list.append("G")
    return list

population = {}

def createfly (x):
    return ({"dna":x , "age":0})

for i in range(0,startingpop):
    population[i] = (createfly(gennew()))

print (population)

def reproduce (x , y):
    combos = []
    childfly = []
    for i in range (0,11):
        combos.append((population[x]["dna"][i], population[y]["dna"][i]))

    for i in range(0,len(combos)):
        x = randint(0,1)
        childfly.append(combos[i][x])
    return childfly

#each gener**strong text**ation what happens
while len(population) > 0:
    for i in population:
        population[i]["age"] = population[i]["age"] + 1
        if population[i]["age"] > deathage:
            population.pop(i)
    flies = []
    for i in population:
        flies.append(i)
    for i in range(max(flies), (max(flies) + howmanynewflies)):
        whichflyone = int(random.choice(list(population.keys())))
        whichflytwo = int(random.choice(list(population.keys())))
        population [i] = createfly(reproduce(whichflyone,whichflytwo))
    print ()
    print ()
    print(population)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've marked below where your error occurs. What is happening is you're iterating `population` and trying to remove elements at the same time. You can't do this, imagine if you iterated a 10 element list, and in the first iteration removed all 10 elements, python would now try to iterate 9 more elements that don't exist.

```
#each gener**strong text**ation what happens
while len(population) > 0:
    for i in population:
        population[i]["age"] = population[i]["age"] + 1
        if population[i]["age"] > deathage:
            population.pop(i) # ERROR
    flies = []
    for i in population:
        flies.append(i)
    for i in range(max(flies), (max(flies) + howmanynewflies)):
        whichflyone = int(random.choice(list(population.keys())))
        whichflytwo = int(random.choice(list(population.keys())))
        population [i] = createfly(reproduce(whichflyone,whichflytwo))
    print ()
    print ()
    print(population)
```

To fix this, instead of removing elements (with `pop`), you could mark elements for removal (say by adding them to a list), and removing outside of the loop:

```
#each gener**strong text**ation what happens
while len(population) > 0:
    removals = []
    for i in population:
        population[i]["age"] = population[i]["age"] + 1
        if population[i]["age"] > deathage:
            removals.append(i)
    for key in removals:
        # population.pop(key) would also work.
        del population[key]
    flies = []
    for i in population:
        flies.append(i)
    for i in range(max(flies), (max(flies) + howmanynewflies)):
        whichflyone = int(random.choice(list(population.keys())))
        whichflytwo = int(random.choice(list(population.keys())))
        population [i] = createfly(reproduce(whichflyone,whichflytwo))
    print ()
    print ()
    print(population)
```

Now your code runs, although it doesn't appear to halt. If that's your intended behaviour then great - but otherwise you may have further bugs. (For example you only remove one fly per cycle, since your populations are 30 flies aged 0..30, and you always add a new one in the next cycle, so your while loop will never break).

Comment: Remember to mark the question as correct if I've answered it to your satisfaction - this avoids other users trying to answer the already answered question.

Answer (score 1):

Tip: your `gennew ():` could be written simply as

```
def gennew():
    return random.sample('ATCG', 10)
```

Besides, doing something like:

```
for i in range(0,startingpop):
    population[i] = (createfly(gennew()))
```

is almost* pointless (unless you store the "name" of your group), you could do

```
population = [createfly(gennew()) for i in range(startingpop)]
```

You would get around with a list much easier imo than with a dict in this case.